# Why are my some of my larger cytoscape networks invisible?

Tags: string, networking, invisible, cytoscape

```
Cytoscape version 3.7.2
MacOS 10.14.6
Processor 2.5GHz i7
Memory 16GB 2133MHz
```

I'm quite new, so apologies if this is a common question.

I've been using Cytoscape to view String networks overlayed with with expression data. So far it's been working fine for small networks (20-40 nodes, <2000 edges), but when I upload some of my larger networks (50-100 proteins, >9000 edges) they are essentially invisible (or at least nodes appear as large indiscrete blocks of colour with no text or outlines). Nodes do become visible when I click on a 'blob', but then disappear when I release.

Indescrete node image:
[image]

I noticed when the network was uploading (tsv file from string) it said many of the lines could not be parsed, but I don't know if this is relevant.

Any advice greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Cytoscape automatically lowers rendering detail to improve rendering performance. That is why the nodes look like plain rectangles. To disable this go to the View menu and select Show Graphics Details.